# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [13, 26]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, confusion-matrix

This is my **predictions** outcome

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

and this is the confusion_matrix() function

```
cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels, predictions[:,0])
```

My query is how this confusion_matrix() functions works and how to solve this issue?
As I am a novice it will be really helpful if anyone can give me a little explanation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is primarily due to the shape of the arrays not being similar. Please check the arrays with `test_labels.shape` etc. Then use the `reshape` method or split them properly so that the shapes match.